# How to apply Android Theme.DeviceDefault customization across all applications?

Tags: android, themes

I am new to Android UI customization. I need to modify few actionMode and actionBar resources of Theme.Holo and Theme.Holo.Light and I need changes to be reflected in all apps (including base apps like People, Email, Phone, Mms). I am using android 4.0.4 sources.

From http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html, I understand that themes_device_defaults.xml is the place to customize the themes.

But after trying for some time, i realized that all base apps (e.g. Contacts) activities define their theme style based on Theme.Holo or Theme.Holo.Light.

Shouldn't all base apps activities uses Themes  with parent Theme.DeviceDefault.Light or Theme.DeviceDefault to support customization via themes_device_default.xml.

Am i missing something ? Is there any way to customize a theme which gets applied to all apps w/o changing every app's  res/style.xml

Thanks & regards,
Anuj